# How to get the user associated to another model DRF. ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, nested, django-filter

I want to check that the card number is exists and then get the associated user to that card number. A user can have multiple card numbers. How do I filter to get the user from the card number entered?

Models:

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

```
email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name="Email Field", max_length=60, unique=True)
dateJoined = models.DateTimeField(
    verbose_name="Date Joined", auto_now_add=True)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Last Login", auto_now=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# Parameters that we want to know about the user
first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="First Name", max_length=100)
last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Lasst Name", max_length=100)



USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

objects = CustomUserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def tokens(self):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token)
    }

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_superuser

def has_module_pers(self, app_label):
    return True
```

class cardModel(models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='card_numbers',null = True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

card_number = models.IntegerField(
    verbose_name="Card Number", blank=True, null=True, default=None, unique=True)

def __int__(self):
    return self.card_number
```

Serializer:

class CheckCard(serializers.Serializer):

```
card_number = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
class Meta:
    fields = ['card_number','user']
    read_only_fields = ['user']
```

Views:

class CheckCardAPI(APIView):
permission_classes = [AllowAny]
serializer_class = CheckCard

```
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    card_number = request.data.get('card_number','')

    if cardModel.objects.filter(card_number=card_number).exists():
        user = User.objects.filter(card_numbers=card_number)
        tokens, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({'token':tokens.key},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else: 
        return Response({'error':'card is not registered'},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a single user based on card number, so your query

```
user = User.objects.filter(card_numbers=card_number)
```

returns a list. Maybe you would need to use

```
user = User.objects.get(card_numbers=card_number)
```

to get an object or use

```
value_list(id, flat=True)
```

with filter.

Comment: i had tried user = User.objects.get(card_numbers=card_number)  and it also doesn't work and I get the error Accounts.models.CustomUser.DoesNotExist: CustomUser matching query does not exist.
Even though I know the card_number has successfully been made for that user

Comment: wait the above query was just to explain how to fetch a single object. this is not correct query.

Comment: Try with User.objects.get(id=cardModel.objects.get(card_numbers=card_number).user) or modify a little to match exactly for what you are looking. Check if  cardModel.objects.get(card_numbers=card_number).user is returning your userID.

Comment: Figured it out. Had to go:
pk = cardModel.objects.get(card_number=card_number)
user = User.objects.get(card_numbers=pk)

Comment: pk = cardModel.objects.get(card_number=card_number) will give you only the CardModel Object. and pk = cardModel.objects.get(card_number=card_number).user will give you user related to that object. Mark .user at the end.  You can not write User.objects.get(card_numbers=pk) because User model has no card number field. But you can write User.objects.get(id=pk) coz user model has id field and also pk should have a .user at end.